# Can't hide jQuery validation plugin's error label

Tags: jquery, css, hover, hide

I'm using jQuery validation plugin for my form. One of my element inside a form is like this:

```
<form name="registrationForm" id="registrationForm" action="" method="POST">
    <span class="component-wrapper">
        <input type="text" name="textStreetName" size="50" value="<?php echo $field['textStreetName'];?>"/>
    </span>
</form>
```

And this is the validation for the form above:

```
$("#registrationForm").validate({
    rules:{
        textStreetName: {required: true}
    }
});
```

The validation worked nicely. A label with class "error" is popped up saying that that field is required. But when I hover onto the error label, it won't disappear. Here is my CSS:

```
.component-wrapper {position: relative;}

label.error {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 20%;
    z-index: 100;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    font-size: 10pt;
    width: 280px;
    padding: 2px;
}

label.error:hover {
    display: none;
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my CSS?

Comment: logic flaw ... as soon as label hidden it is no longer able to be hovered so normal css takes effect ... is a recursive situation

Comment: BTW, why do you want to remove an error message on `hover`?  I've never seen a form behave like that.  The invalid field will continue to be invalid until something is done about it.  (Typically, error messages are only removed when the input data is corrected.)

Comment: @Sparky because error label that popped up over the textbox is annoying for users when they want to input something on the textbox.

Comment: So then don't let the message cover the `input`.  Again, never saw a form do anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment :

`display: none` removes the element, it doesn't occupy space anymore thus it's not hovered anymore, so it shows.

You could set the opacity to 0 :

```
label.error:hover {
     opacity: 0;
}
```

As shown in the fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/6gBSL/

Comment: other ideas I had are set text indent offscreen, remove background and border...or use jQuery to hide when hover parent

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6gBSL/3/ this contains hacks for our beloved IE. (God how I hate this browser).